# Allow user to set password after creating account using Ansible

Tags: passwords, ansible, ubuntu-16.04

I have the following playbook which I am using to create a new user on an Ubuntu 16.04 host:

```
---
- hosts: all 
  become: yes 
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
  - name: Create user guybrush
    user: name=guybrush comment="Guybrush Threepwood" shell=/bin/bash groups=pirates append=yes

  - name: Copy SSH key for guybrush
    authorized_key: user=guybrush key={{ lookup("file", "/home/guybrush/.ssh/id_rsa.pub") }}
```

However when I log in as the new user and try to se my password using `passwd` I get asked for my (current) UNIX password. Given that no password has been set for user I'm not sure why I am asked for it.

How can I fix my playbook so that newly created users can easily set their passwords after logging in the first time?

Comment: You are creating a user with key based authentication. And you want the user to change the password?

Comment: I'm creating a user that can initially log in using their public key; once they've logged in it would be nice if they could change their password as they will need it if they use `sudo` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set password to empty line, so `passwd` will not ask for old password.
You also can set it as expired to force user to change password on first login.

```
- user: name=jsmith password=""
- authorized_key: user=jsmith key={{ lookup("file", "/somepath/id_rsa.pub") }}
- command: chage -d 0 jsmith
```

If there are security concerns with empty password, you can set it to some random predefined one and play with welcome ssh message to display it on first login.

Comment: What OS are you using? Empty password approach does not work for me on fresh Debian 10 system. Even with empty password, user still needs to know old password to change it on first login. Note: I am NOT installing a public ssh key in authorized_keys like you are. But I don't see how that would change this behavior.